# Flask Application TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python, html, postgresql, flask

I am getting started with Flask and trying to create a simple database web application.

It renders 2 html-templates:

- `show_all.html` which shows the data of a database table
- `new.html` which is a form to insert data in to the table

The `show_all.html` renders correctly. When I click on the submit-button on the `new.html` I get the following error message:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

**app.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import psycopg2

DB_URL = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pw}@{url}/{db}'.format(user='*******',pw='******',url='******',db='*****')

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URL
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class test (db.Model):
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"SaubannerDB"}
    id1 = db.Column('id1', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name1 = db.Column(db.String(10))

    def __init__(self, name1, id1):
        self.name1 = name1
        self.id1 = id1

@app.route('/')
def show_all():
    return render_template ('show_all.html', tests=test.query.all())

@app.route('/new', methods=['GET','POST'])
def new():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if not request.form['name1'] or not request.form['id1']:
        flash ('Please enter all fields')
    else:
        name1 = test(request.form['name1'])
        id1 = test(request.form['id1'])
        entry = (name1,id1)

        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('new.html')

  return render_template('new.html')

app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5050)
app.debug = True`
```

The `new.html` file looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <form method="post" action="/new">
      <label for="name1"/label><br>
      <input type="text" name="name1" placeholder="name"><br>
      <label for="id1"/label><br>
      <input type="text" name="id1" placeholder="id"><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>`
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why is your ```__init__()``` method is outside of the class?

Answer (score 2):

Found it out. The following Code works, note the changes for the variable "entry":

```
from flask import Flask, request, flash, url_for, redirect, render_template
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import psycopg2

DB_URL = 'postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pw}@{url}/{db}'.format(user='*******',pw='******',url='******',db='*****')


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = DB_URL
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class test (db.Model):
    __table_args__ = {"schema":"SaubannerDB"}
    id1 = db.Column('id1', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name1 = db.Column(db.String(10))

    def __init__(self, name1, id1):
        self.name1 = name1
        self.id1 = id1

@app.route('/')
def show_all():
    return render_template ('show_all.html', tests=test.query.all())

@app.route('/new', methods=['GET','POST'])
def new():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    if not request.form['name1'] or not request.form['id1']:
        flash ('Please enter all fields')
    else:
        entry = test(request.form['id1'],
                      request.form['name1'])

        db.session.add(entry)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('new.html')

  return render_template('new.html')

app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5050)
app.debug = True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look here it seems that the init argument is only in the pre-release version:
https://github.com/teracyhq/flask-classful/releases
If that is the case, they shouldn't have the init_argument in the documentation. It's unprofessional.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32301829)